# Get the order of parameters for python function?

Tags: python, reflection

I have the following function:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print "Hello"
```

Let's say I know it exists, and I know it takes three parameters named a, b and c, but I don't know in which order.

I want to be able to call foo given a dictionary like:

```
args = { "a": 1, "b" : 17, "c": 23 }
```

Is there a way to find out in which order the parameters are to be passed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to; let Python figure that out for you:

```
foo(**args)
```

This applies your dictionary as keyword arguments, which is perfectly legal. You can use the arguments to `foo()` in any order when you use keyword arguments:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
...     print a, b, c
... 
>>> foo(c=3, a=5, b=42)
5 42 3
>>> args = {'a': 1, 'b' : 17, 'c': 23}
>>> foo(**args)
1 17 23
```

You can still figure out the exact order, using the [`inspect.getargspec()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

But why have a dog and bark yourself?